# Hive query select one column depending on another column during group by

Tags: sql, hadoop, group-by, hive, aggregate

There are similar questions out there, but the solution of them can't quite solve my problem. Consider the following table:

```
id type time
1  a    1
1  a    2
1  b    3
2  b    1
2  b    2
```

What I want is the id with the smallest time and the type associated with that time, so the result should be:

```
id type time
1  a    1
2  b    1
```

(if there is a tie in time with different types, choosing any type is acceptable)
My current query looks like:

```
SELECT id, type, min(time) FROM t GROUP BY id, type;
```

which fails to address the duplicate type issue.
Is there a query I can do to achieve that?
Many thanks

Comment: i have similar problem too, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `group by`, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

--Using sub query also we can achieve it.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    id INT
    ,[type] CHAR(1)
    ,[time] INT
    )

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES 
(1,'a',1),
(1,'a',2),
(1,'b',3),
(2,'b',1),
(2,'b',2)

SELECT DISTINCT T.id
    ,T.type
    ,DT.MinTime
FROM #Temp T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(TIME) AS MinTime
    FROM #Temp
    GROUP BY [TYPE]
    ) AS DT ON T.[time] = DT.MinTime
```